# How can I stop a video when it is replaced (Jquery)?

Tags: jquery, video, methods, replacewith

Jquery:

```
$(function () {

$('.videos').hide();
$(".bat").click(function () {
    $('.videos').hide();
    $('.morcego').slideDown();
    $('.default').replaceWith(".morcego");
});
$('.hit').click(function () {
    $('.videos').hide();
    $('.careca').slideDown();
    $('.default').replaceWith(".careca");
});
$('.metro').click(function () {
    $('.videos').hide();
    $('.metro-last').slideDown();
    $('.default').replaceWith(".metro-last");
    });
});
```

HTML: `
    
        
            Watch and listen our reviews

```
        <iframe width="900" height="400" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tl39XPeb7UE?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen class="videos morcego img-responsive"></iframe>

        <iframe width="900" height="400" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/g7uYfhWNvrA?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen class="videos careca img-responsive"></iframe>

        <iframe width="900" height="400" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/FDIjP6X9f98?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen class="videos metro-last img-responsive">></iframe>

    </div>

    <div class="videos-list-video">
        <h3 class="align-center">Popular Videos</h3>
        <div class=img-list>

            <img src="img/batman_videos.jpg" class="img-responsive bat">
        </div>
        <div class=img-list>

            <img src="img/hitman_videos.jpg" class="img-responsive hit">
        </div>
        <div class=img-list>

            <img src="img/metro_videos.png" class="img-responsive metro">
        </div>


    </div>

</div>
```

The program works fine but when the video is replaced, the other one won't stop playing and you hear it. I guess i can't use the replaceWith() method...any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `&enablejsapi=1` to your iframe src attribute

Example

```
 <iframe width="900" height="400" 
  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tl39XPeb7UE?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0&enablejsapi=1" 
  frameborder="0" allowfullscreen class="videos morcego img-responsive"></iframe>
```

and call

```
jQuery("iframe")[0].contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command",
"func":"stopVideo","args":""}', '*');
```

to stop the iframe video, you can use  `"func":"pauseVideo"` to pause the video

Check the demo

> JSFiddle : [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/h2a8qfh4/1/)

Comment: It works, but only for the Batman video. If bat is playing and you call other, the Bat stops, but if Hitman is playing and you call other, it doesn't stop. Same is for Metro...I don't get it...

Answer (score 1):

Before hiding the `.video`, remove the `src` in iframe.

```
$(this).find('.videos').attr('src', '');
```

Comment: You mean this?


$(function () {

    $('.videos').hide();
    $(".bat").click(function () {
        $('.videos').hide();
        $(this).find('.videos').attr('src', '');
        $('.morcego').slideDown();
        $('.default').replaceWith(".morcego");
    });
    });
It's not working...

Comment: @icenine To save time, can you put your working code in [Plunker.co](http://plnkr.co/)?